# Error running flutter application on simulators

Tags: flutter, dart, multiplatform, flutter-run

Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): ../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/data_table.dart:1164:41:
Error: Member not found: 'Matrix4.identity'.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

When i type flutter run the above error occurs on the default application without any configurations. I didn't get why the error occurs.

Comment: Try command Flutter clean then pub get and run again.

Comment: i already tried what you suggested but the error keeps on persisting. Its the default app of flutter but this error keeps showing and i didn't even change anything

Comment: Can you share repo link on my email so i can check. Check my email in profile.

Comment: What is your `flutter doctor` output?

Comment: [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

Comment: [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.5, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-x64, locale
    en-PH)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[!] HTTP Host Availability
    ✗ HTTP host "https://cocoapods.org/" is not reachable. Reason: Failed to
      connect to host in 10 seconds

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: There is an error regarding cocoapods but i dont think it affects my run

Comment: I think in your system any internet connectivity issue. just verify internet connection before try flutter pub get because on first time all packages will download on your machine.

Comment: @VishalZaveri my connection is strong. This is the output when i run it on android emulator.                                                                                                   
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/lap052user/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1151

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/lap052user/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: @VishalZaveri does the error occur due to flutter.gradle?

Comment: @VishalZaveri i solved the problem using flutter pub cache repair.

Comment: Ohh great. Just add your answer and close this questions so it will helps to others. Happy coding:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just run `flutter pub cache repair`, this error occurs due to corrupted resources etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run from Xcode or terminal with command `flutter run`